# Removing from a list

Tags: javascript, html

I have an add user and a remove user button. I have functions that take whatever is in a text-input and add or remove it from a select. This is my js code:

```
var addedUsers = [];

function add(){
    var form = document.getElementById('form')
    var emailInput = form.elements.typer
    let email = emailInput.value
    emailInput.value = ""

    var select = document.getElementById('users')
    var option = document.createElement("option")
    option.text = email

    emailInput.focus()
    if (addedUsers.indexOf(email) == -1){
        addedUsers.push(email)       
        select.add(option)
    } else {
        alert("This user is already one of your recipients!");
    }
}

function rem(){
    var form = document.getElementById('form')
    var emailInput = form.elements.typer
    let email = emailInput.value
    emailInput.value = ""

    var select = document.getElementById('users')
    var options = select.options

    emailInput.focus()
    if (addedUsers.indexOf(email) != -1){
        for (var i = 2; i < options.length; i++){
            if(email === options[i].innerHTML){
                select.remove(i)
                addedUsers.splice(email, 1)
                break
            }
        }
    } else {
        alert("This user is not already one of your recipients!")
    }
}






        <form id="form">
            <div class="recipients">
                <input type="text" class="typer" name="typer">
                <br><br>
                <button onclick="add()" type="button" class="ar">Add User</button>
                <button onclick="rem()" type="button" class="ur">Remove User</button>
                <br><br><br>
                <select id="users" name="users" class="userlist" size="24">
                    <option class="listhead">__________*Recipents*__________</option>
                    <option class="listhead">-------------------------------</option>
                </select>
            </div>   
            <div class="content">
                <button onclick="mail()" class="send">Send</button>
                <br><br>
                <textarea type:"content" name="content" class="typec" cols="113" rows="12"></textarea>
            </div>
        </form>
```

I noticed that I can add nothing at all and remove nothing at all, until an alert comes up. How can I prevent this? Also, if I hit one of the added options in the select, how do I make it show up in the text-input? Thanks!

Comment: Post your HTML code too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Chocolord correctly pointed out, you need to use valid methods, like `appendChild` and `removeChild`, respectively, instead of `add` and `remove`, respectively.

The reason why your program mistakenly thought the users were correctly added was that you actually added them to the array before the actual DOM operation:

```
    addedUsers.push(email)       
    select.add(option)
```

respectively. Make sure you you invert the operation to

```
    select.add(option)
    addedUsers.push(email)
```

Comment: Sorry, that did not help!!

Comment: Oh and also if I hit one of the added options in the select, how do I make it show up in the text-input?

Comment: @Terabyte if you create a JSFiddle with your problem and explain why using the correct Javascript functions and refactoring the code as I have described did not help, what is the problem, then I would take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you don't use the good methods to add and remove options to the select.

You should use `appendChild` to add the option to the select and `removeChild` to remove an option to the select.

example:

```
// in the add() function
select.appendChild(option)

// in the rem() function
select.removeChild(options[i])
```

Documentation:

- [element.appendChild - Reference Web API | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)
- [element.removeChild - Reference Web API | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild)